# How to import Zbrush brushes(files .ZBP) to Blender

Tags: add-on, sculpting, zbrush

I wonder if there is an add-on to use Zbrush brushes in Blender sculpt mode.

Comment: i think you were locking for this ? https://github.com/JoseConseco/GoB

Answer (score 1):

In fact there is a pack of ZBrush sculpting brushes for FREE on the BlendSwap site which could be of your interest...

https://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/86419

Hope it helps buddy, Jan