# ZBrush sculpting brushes equivalents in Blender

Tags: sculpting, zbrush

I'm sculpting a lot recently and most of the sculpt-related tutorials on Youtube are for ZBrush, nevertheless human anatomy knowledge contained therein is universally applicable.

To get more out of those tutorials it would be nice to have a list of brush equivalents, for example when they are talking about "clay buildup" brush in ZBrush, should I use clay or clay strips brush in Blender? Is "clay tubes" in ZBrush Blender's "clay strips"? Does "standard brush" equal "sculpt/draw"? It takes lots of effort and experimentation to find those equivalents with trial and error.

As for the list of Blender's sculpt brushes, I'm using this page:

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21622/1621

Comment: Probably it's better using actual ZBrush for sculpting in particular, taking into account its possibilities of handling with high res models. Blender's sculpt system is good but I don't think it's really has analogues for everything from ZBrush.

Comment: Try this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47885/how-to-import-zbrush-brushesfiles-zbp-to-blender ... there is my answer with link.

Answer (score 11):

During months afetr I asked this question I was able to piece together some experience from various sources that now allows me to answer it, at least partially. I'll probably be editing this answer in the future and adding new items to the list.

The goal was to be able to use gazillion of ZBrush sculpting tutorials from Youtube and use them as a learning tool in Blender Sculpt mode. The conclusion is, in order to understand them, you have to learn ZBrush, there is no way around it. But you don't have to download and use the program itself, you can simply watch a few beginner tutorials. The best way to familiarize yourself with ZBrush basics is the latest playlist by Pixologic, published on 24.06.2016:

[ZClassroom - How to Start with ZBrush](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLMjnnUF3eJFdmpiGBg2ZgcrsjijoC5tvo)

Another source that confirmed you can find some equivalents is a book "Blender 3D By Example":

https://books.google.pl/books?id=gtdOCwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&vq=zbrush#v=onepage&q=zbrush&f=false

[image: Book excerpts]

Here is my list:

```
    ------------------------------------------------------------
ZBrush                      Blender 

Standard   ------------->   SculptDraw 
Dam Standard  ---------->   Crease
Clay Buildup  ---------->   Clay Strips
Move      -------------->   Grab
hPolish   -------------->   Flatten
Trim      -------------->   Scrape/Peak [1]
Pinch     -------------->   Pinch 
Smooth    -------------->   Smooth 
Layer     -------------->   Layer 
Inflate   -------------->   Inflate/Deflate
```

**Some equivalent settings and keystrokes:**

```
ZBrush                      Blender
------------------------------------------------------------
Z-intensity (U)   ------->  Strength (Shift+F)
Draw Size (S)   --------->  Radius (F)
Focal Shift   ----------->  Curve (submenu in the Toolshelf)
Rectangle Mask (Ctrl+LMB)   Box Mask (B)
Erase Mask       -------->  Clear Mask (Alt+M)
Inverse Mask (Ctrl+I) --->  Invert Mask (Ctrl+I)
Polygroups (Ctrl+W) ----->  Face Sets (Draw Face Sets brush in 2.83)
```

[1] *see video by Gleb Alexandrov https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YKPrGh1HTog*